# How to set up 1..0-1 relationship using Code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Based on this [article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), and:

1. Using Fluent Api, and
2. Not having a navigation property in the dependent entity (ie. StudentAddress)

Is it possible to create 1..0-1 relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOptional(e => e.StudentAddress).WithRequired().Map(ca => ca.MapKey(new string[] {"StudentId"});
```